# Use ionic framework with mean.io

Tags: mean.io, ionic-framework

I just started using MEAN.io which is a project for seeding MongoDB, Express, AngularJS and NodeJS. I wonder how I could integrate ionic with it? I used bower to install ionic into bower_components folder, but the js/css file doesn't load automatically. When I manually add ionic.bundle.js and ionic.css into my custom package using

```
  Ionic.aggregateAsset('css', 'ionic.css');
  Ionic.aggregateAsset('js', 'ionic.bundle.js');
```

or

```
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/assets/css/'));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/assets/js/'));
```

I get hundreds of errors from jshint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-> /app/config/env/all.js 
Here you can insert your external libs, in this case ionic main js file.
Do the same with css files. I dont know how Ionic is built, but if it has modular structure, you will also have to inject it into angular module.